# In Paging library, LiveData pagedList updated value is not observing at activity after first time

Tags: android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I am using paging library, inside my viewmodel value of LiveData> liveData;
is updating but obeserver in the activity is not able to observe the change after 1st time . and LivePagedListBuilder returns only LiveData so I am not able to replace it with mutableLivedata .

```
   public class RecipeListViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
   public LiveData<PagedList<RecipeListPojo>> liveData;
       private Context context;

   public RecipeListViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    context=application.getApplicationContext();
}
  public LiveData<PagedList<RecipeListPojo>> init(RecipeDao recipeDao,RecipeFrom recipeFrom,String orderBy) {
  String query=ChefDatabase.getInstance(context).recipeListQueryBuilder(recipeFrom);
    query=query +ORDER_BY+orderBy;
    SimpleSQLiteQuery simpleSQLiteQuery = new SimpleSQLiteQuery(query);
    try {
        liveData = new LivePagedListBuilder(recipeDao.getAllRecipesList(simpleSQLiteQuery), 6).build();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return liveData;

}
```